# .Net Core MVC Web App - passing value from View to Controller in a Form not working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, postback, asp.net-core-2.2

I've read other posts on here to try and fix my issue but no luck.

I have a form, that is based on a simple model.

```
public class Image
{       
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

}
```

In my view, I have a form which displays an image:

```
@model Uploader.Models.Image

<h1>View Image</h1>



<form asp-controller="Images" asp-action="Download" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <img src="~/Images/@Model.FileName" />


    <input type="submit" value="Download Image" class="btn btncolour btn-primary" />

    @Model.FileName

</form>
```

That last Model.Filename, I was just testing to see if the value is present (which it is). From what i can see, everything is fine here, when I submit this form, the values from my model (specifically Image.FileName) should be posted back to the server.

my controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(Image image)
    {
        if (image.FileName == null)
            return Content("filename not present");

        var path = Path.Combine(
                       Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                       "wwwroot", image.FileName);

        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
```

My code hits this method upon postback, but `image.FileName` is always null, even though on the View itself, I can see that `model.FileName` does contain a value.

Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileName is used for src of image but not as an input. Only input field values are sent in request when you click submit.

Try adding text input with name="FileName", then enter some value and click submit. Then you should be able to receive this value in controller method.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. I guess I can make this field hidden too? As  Idont need an input field on my page

Comment: Sure, you can make it hidden and it will do the job.